# TableView drawRect and UIButtons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a complex `TableViewCell` with a good number of labels, images, and buttons. I got everything working using `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, and `UIButton`, but to increase performance I'm in the process of porting as much of this as I can over to `drawRect`.

I know a lot of people use `drawRect` to optimize TableViews, but I haven't been able to find anything about how to incorporate buttons with `drawRect`.

So how would I incorporate a button (with separate images for normal and highlighted) into `drawRect`?

Comment: actually if you are reusing your cells it should be fast enough, but in the case if it is really slow... what about to draw images and labels in context in `drawRect` method, but leave buttons as they are?

Comment: Yeah, I'll see if I can get away with that, I just wondered if some developers might've been putting their UIButtons in `drawRect` to maximize performance even more.

Comment: I don't think it is worth putting buttons to drawRect. If you have tons of buttons, you may separate your cells into different types of cells (in the case if your cell is higher than screen :) )

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860817/abtableviewcell-adding-a-uibutton